Anchor deployment on Solana mainnet is failing
I'm trying to deploy the contract to Solana mainnet and it's failing.
Deployment command used:
#!/bin/bash

RPC_URL=RPC_URL_FROM_QUICKNODE

anchor build
anchor deploy --provider.cluster $RPC_URL -- --with-compute-unit-price 10000

Terminal output:
Deploying cluster: RPC_URL_FROM_QUICKNODE
Upgrade authority: /Users/apple/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "vault"...
Program path: /BASE_PATH_OF_PROJECT/target/deploy/vault.so...
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
⠂  47.6% | Timed out resending 332 transactions...  [block height 252628759; re-sign in 62 blocks]                                                     thread 'main' panicked at quic-client/src/nonblocking/quic_client.rs:111:14:
QuicLazyInitializedEndpoint::create_endpoint bind_in_range: Os { code: 24, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Too many open files" }
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
⠂  47.6% | Timed out resending 332 transactions...  [block height 252628759; re-sign in 62 blocks]
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(25856)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

The same contract is deployed on devnet and localnet and working fine.
Versions used:

anchor-cli 0.30.0
solana-cli 1.18.11 (src:c78a9720; feat:3469865029, client:SolanaLabs)

Generally when the contract deployment fails, it shares the seed phrase to recover the funds using the buffer account. This didn't happen this time.
So rent is deducted and contract also didn't deploy.
Where I need help:

How to get the deducted funds back ? (Rent was 4.5 SOL approx)
How to deploy the contract on mainnet, as it's failing repeatedly ?

I have tried changing RPC providers also.
I have tried increasing the compute unit price also.
It's taking a very long time (approximately 1.5 hours) for showing the above terminal output.
On devnet, it's complete in 45 secs - 1 min max.




I was able to solve my issue by doing the following:
How to get the deducted funds back ? (Rent was 4.5 SOL approx)

I checked the transactions done from my account on Solana explorer and took the latest record.
In the txn info, I started one by one checking the involved accounts whose balance was approx 4.5 SOL.
I was able to find the account which was storing the funds.
I then used the solana program close command directly (since I didn't had the seed phrase to first write to a buffer account).
This process gave my SOL tokens back.

How to deploy the contract on mainnet, as it's failing repeatedly ?

I upgraded the solana CLI to the latest version and the anchor deployment command worked instantly.
Not sure why it's was still working perfectly on devnet and localnet with the 1.18.11 version but required the latest 1.18.15 version for mainnet.

